# Wirelessly connect 5" resistive touch screen to computer

Tags: wireless, touchscreen, mouse

Figured out display, just need to transmit touch signals wirelessly.

What I have is a 5" monitor with a USB touch overlay connected to my laptop with a USB cable.

I've done quite a bit of research and found solutions only for analog sticks, keyboards and mouse; but none for touch.

What I'm understanding is a micro-controller and a BLE module is needed. Only thing left would be the code.

Since the analog input is already converted to digital and outputs that data via USB what can I do to transmit that data wirelessly?

Also the computer recognizes this device as a USB mouse

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's not recognised as a mouse,  that would be really annoying.  - touch screens do absolute position, mice do relative movement.  no doubt it is recognised as some sort of poiinter device.

Comment: "The touch screen shows up as a USB mouse so no special drivers needed." taken directly from the products description: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2260

I understand it's an absolute position device and knowing that how can I program an Arduino Mini Pro with a BLE module to relay that data wirelessly?

Comment: not the first fime marketers have made untrue claims. anyway , you'd need  to make the arduino act as a USB host. this is not going to happen unless the touch screen is low speed USB. and then it'd just be really tricky

Comment: @Jasen True, though any modern computer would have drivers for both, so *no special drivers needed* claim still holds.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a 'wireless USB hub'.

- Place this at your monitor, plug the monitor touch USB into it.
- Insert the receiver into your laptop.

Comment: I've been searching for that for the past couple of weeks and every product is either discontinued or unavailable. Iogear used to have them but now I think it's only for data transfer and not commands.

Comment: [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Belkin-F5L009-5-Port-Network-USB/dp/B000QSN3O6) have them and eBay. Mouse motion is 'data'. USB protocol won't know what it's carrying.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't buy a wireless USB hub, here's something you could pretty easily build using a Raspberry Pi or any similar single-board computer running Linux (using something smaller like an [Orange Pi Zero](https://www.armbian.com/orange-pi-zero/) would make sense):

- Connect your touchscreen to RPi's USB port
- Make sure the RPi connects to your WiFi automatically
- Start [USB/IP daemon](https://sourceforge.net/p/usbip/git-windows/ci/master/tree/trunk/userspace/README) on it (install with `apt-get install usbip` if missing)
- Install a USB/IP client for your computer (I guess you need one for [Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/usbip/files/usbip_windows/))
- Export the touchscreen device and enjoy!